# htaccess 301 redirect folder, but not subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect from:

http://example.com/folder

to http://example.com/newfolder

But leave:

http://example.com/folder/subfolder

Where it is. Is this possible? I can't seem to make it happen without causing a heap of redirect chaos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just ran into this and here's the solution I came up with. I prefer this method because it doesn't redirect any subdirectory.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/root-directory[/]?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/root-directory/+[/]?
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: billynoah's answer below is a better and cleaner solution for this.

Comment: I would like to redirect only home to another site. not sub pages. `example.com` to `newsite.com`

Answer (score 38):

Jestep's answer above redirects "/root-directory" but fails to redirect "/root-directory/".  This can be fixed and simplified by simply:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder/?$
RewriteRule (.*) /newfolder [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect "/folder" and "/folder/" but leave all sub-directories alone.

Comment: Much better than my example.

Comment: old but gold.. upvote from my side

Answer (score 7):

I've tried other methods here with mixed success. I am no Apache expert by any means, but here is the simple one-liner that works every time for me. I just use `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect` and include a very simple RegEx to end the match at or just before the trailing slash, meaning that subdirectories should never qualify as a match.

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder[/]?$ /newfolder`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder[/]?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/subfolder[/]?
RewriteRule (.*) /newfolder/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This should redirect /folder to /newfolder but leave out /folder/subfolder

Answer (score 2):

If `mod-rewrite` isn't enabled or you are unable to use `RewriteRule` directive on your server, you can use `RedirectMatch` directive of [mod-alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) which is the default module of apache httpd server.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/?$ http://example.com/newfolder/
```

This will 301 redirect `/folder/` to `/newfolder/` .

Answer (score 1):

Which server are you using?
You could for example use mod_rewrite if you use apache and do something like this

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteOptions Inherit
    RedirectMatch permanent ^/folder/$ http://example.com/newfolder
    #I haven't tested the above redirect btw ^
```

and put that in a .htaccess file in your /folder/ directory (assuming you can alter apache's settings, meaning you have the option AllowOverride All in that virtual host)

Here's some more info http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: This is the best answer because one can use it from a virtual host in the Apache vhost.conf file. I tested it, it works. Thanks, cyph3r!