# CDN URL to root folder / prevent duplicate content?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

For a image gallery I have to install a CDN Domain.

Default Domain:

```
http://www.example.com
Apache folder: /html/mywebsite
```

CDN Domain:

```
http://cdn.example.com
Apache folder: /html/mywebsite
```

The CDN Domain need the same Apache folder for url rewrite reasons etc.

Problem:

```
http://cdn.example.com
and
http://www.example.com
```

open the same website and this is bad. I cant rewrite (301) from cdn to www because I have to serve the images from the CDN. Also I cant use a 403:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* / [F]
```

because image urls from the cdn

```
http://cdn.example.com/images/test.jpg
```

get also a 403. Is it possible to make a 403 only for the root folder and not for subfolders or do you have a better idea?

btw. robots.txt is also bad, because images from the cdn should be indexed. A htaccess solution would be great.

Comment: Were you looking for something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17709366/4486839 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the root (and any documents in the root) of `cdn.example.com` to go to `www.example.com` and each domain uses a separate VirtualHost, you can use something as simple as

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/?(.+\.php)$ http://www.example.com/$1
```

in the VirtualHost container for `cdn.example.com`. Obviously, you can tweak the regular expression to match your site's files.

See the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html) for some reasons why this is preferable to using mod_rewrite. It's simpler, easier to maintain, and in many cases will result in better performance.

Answer (score 0):

At first, thank you softwariness and dartnow

@dartnow:

Your solution is working for my question. Thanks for your time.

There is a better solution:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?i:php|jpe?g|ico|js|txt|css|pdf|zip|gz|gif|png)$
RewriteRule .* http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

i:php in the cond is for images that comes from a php document.
    http://metasun.com/b/prevent-cdn-caching-webpages-avoid-duplicate-content