# URL redirect - best practice for redirecting to subdomain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a Drupal installation, whose services module drives a mobile application; which is to say that I cannot move the Drupal installation.

However the actual website is out of style and for marketing purposes I would like to replace it with a WordPress installation on a subdomain or directory.

What is the best practice for redirecting all traffic to www.domain.com to www.domain.com/wordpress without affecting traffic to www.domain.com/any.html/php?

Comment: is there a specific url you want not to redirect? or just anything that's different from the root domain?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14734496/1426539

Comment: Only the root domain, leaving all other folders and pages where they are.