# htaccess redirect directory but not files in directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect from:

http://example.com/folder

to http://example.com/

But leave:

http://example.com/folder/file

Is this possible?

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901984/htaccess-301-redirect-folder-but-not-subfolders) but it only works with subfolders and not files.

Comment: any request to website like  http://example.com/ should be as is and go internally to http://example.com/folder right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based in your question ,There are two scenarios and it is up to you to choose the suitable one :

**First:**

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s/folder/?\sHTTP.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$    / [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^$    /folder/ [L]
```

You catch the both requests `http://example.com/folder` or `http://example.com/folder/` then redirect any one of them externally to `http://example.com/` but still get the data internally from that folder.

**Second:**

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /folder/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$    /  [R=302,L]
```

You catch the both requests `http://example.com/folder` or `http://example.com/folder/` then redirect any one of them to `http://example.com/` .

with these two scenarios any request to `http://example.com/folder/file` will be as is.

**Note:** if any one is ok , change `R=302` to `R=301` to be permanent redirection

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/file$
RewriteRule (.*) / [R=301,L]
```