# 301 redirect www version to non for only a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

Trying to 301 redirect all urls to `non-www` **only** in a specific subdirectory. for example:

```
https://www.example.com/test
```

to

```
https://example.com/test
```

But not redirect any other subdirectories for example:
`https://www.example.com/test1` should keep the `www`

more examples:

```
https://www.example.com/test/country/city
```

to

```
https://example.com/test/country/city
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate, see an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14734496/5152519

Comment: This is a www and non-www 301 redirect question but for all URLs in only one subdirectory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to redirect your `www` urls to `non-www` for a specific directory :

```
RewriteEngine on

#the directory the rule should apply to
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/DirName/  [NC]
#check if the host  string starts with "www"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
#redirect all www urls to non-www
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI}  [L,R=301]
```